# How to print pdf file in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, printing

I need to print pdf file using React-JS, I am getting that pdf file in base64 format...

I tried using react-to-print package but it prints white screen.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print

[https://codeat21.com/how-to-printing-and-download-pdf-file-in-react-with-react-to-print/#:~:text=React%20pdf%20and%20download%20file,js](https://codeat21.com/how-to-printing-and-download-pdf-file-in-react-with-react-to-print/#:%7E:text=React%20pdf%20and%20download%20file,js).

Please help me... Thanks in advance

Comment: any reason why you need to use react for that?
you can use standard HTML solutions with embedded or iframe.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.